# Can I use the reshape + transpose trick to create tiling with overlap?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a very large array that I would like tile with **overlap**.  For example, if the array looks like

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
p q r s t
u v w x y
```

I want to break it up into 3 x 3 tiles, where each tile overlaps its neighbor by 1 on each side:

```
a b c    c d e
f g h    h i j
k l m    m n o

k l m    m n o
p q r    r s t
u v w    w x y
```

The "reshape and transpose trick" (described in https://www.kaggle.com/c/hubmap-kidney-segmentation/discussion/202171) is an approach for tiling a large array in Python (and other languages)
that allows **abutting** (not **overlapping**) tiles to be extracted and represented *without having to copy the underlying data array*.

What I'm wondering is:  Can this trick be used if we want to tiles to overlap, as shown above?
If so, how?

Comment: Read the `as_strided` docs, paying attention to its warnings.  While this makes a `view` without copying, further actions with the `view` may result in a copy, and blow up your memory.  It's safest to do reduction actions like `mean` on the tiles.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done through reshaping alone, but it can be done using the lower-level [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) function, carefully setting the [`shape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) and [`strides`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) parameters:

```python
>>> x = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)

>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

>>> y = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape=(2, 2, 3, 3),
...                                     strides=(80, 16, 40, 8))

>>> y
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2],
         [ 5,  6,  7],
         [10, 11, 12]],

        [[ 2,  3,  4],
         [ 7,  8,  9],
         [12, 13, 14]]],


       [[[10, 11, 12],
         [15, 16, 17],
         [20, 21, 22]],

        [[12, 13, 14],
         [17, 18, 19],
         [22, 23, 24]]]])
```

The second array is split into overlapping tiles, and you can confirm that the two arrays share the same memory:

```python
>>> np.byte_bounds(x) == np.byte_bounds(y)
True
```

Therefore y is a new view of x.
The 'shape' specifies y's shape in each dimension. Within each dimension, the 'stride' specifies the distance between its elements' starting positions, depending on x's original memory arrangement.